# Changing displayed value

Tags: onclick

please how do i change the display value of a button when i click on it.
Say "hello" was being displayed on the button, then when i click it changes to "hi" in Reactjs

```
export default function Change () {

return (
   <div>
     <button>hello</button> (this displays 'hello')
   </div>

//the above changes when clicked on

   <div>
     <button>hi</button> (displays 'hi' when clicked on)
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can even accomplish that inside you HTML: `<button onclick="this.innerText='hi'">Hello</button>`. Or if you need a toggle: `<button onclick="this.innerText=this.innerText==='Hello'?'Hi':'Hello'">Hello</button>`